# Solution change from ASP.NET MVC 2 to?

Tags: sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-2, saas

I have been working on an ASP.NET MVC 2 app similar to SQL MDS. The app which we call as ADMIN app is for implementors to setup non transactional customer data to bring them on board.

The app was however built for targetting a SQL DB on a single environment UAT/LIVE/QA etc. In a nutshell the app is deployed together with DB.

The new requirement is - app should target multiple DBs. In other words a customer data keyed in should be staged/migrated to UAT & subsequently to LIVE environment. This will ensure customer data does not have to be keyed in multiple times. This new requirement has caught me offguard.

I cannot go with single site targetting multiple DBs coz the environments are seggregated and no cross env network access is allowed. Which is fair.

Another approach I was thinking was to export the entitties objectgraph as a package (since I am using LINQ2SQL) to be imported into the next environment using serialize/deserialize. However I am afraid I might run into issues with IDs and referential integrity. Has anyone tried this?

As I use DI/IoC so the architecture is loosely coupled.  What other solutions could I try without much recourse to development efforts? Should I go with a Winform approach and mandate implementors to have network access to all the SQL servers?

Any thoughts will be very much appreciated...
Daks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do all the databases have the same schema? If so, can't you simply change connection strings on the fly and connect to which ever database you need to?

Comment: All DBs do share a common schema. However I cannot go with single site targetting multiple DBs spread on seperate environments (QA/UAT/LIVE). All are seggregated and no cross environment network access is allowed.

Comment: I feel your pain. At my last company we had about 40 databases to keep in sync. We used http://www.red-gate.com/products/SQL_Packager/index.htm and SQL Comapre liked them a lot.

Comment: Although I haven't trialled it yet. From the looks of t SQL_Packager seems to be the most suitable candidate to accomplish what I need.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your issue correctly, I think you could consider using [ETL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Etl) to transfer the data between different databases whenever it is updated.  Rhino ETL is a good tool for moving the data around.

[Here](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2008/01/16/Rhino-ETL-2.0.aspx) is a link about usage and [here](https://github.com/ayende/rhino-etl) is a link to the git repository.